# Finding objects with $or operator and two nested $in conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to build a query using Mongoose to find an object if its keyword is in a list of keywords OR if its `artistName` is within an list of `artistNames`. I can get one or the other search conditions to work, but not both!

Here's my code:

```
  Artwork.find({ $or: [{ 
      artworkKeywords: {
      $in: keywordArray}, _p_artist: {$in: artistArray}}]}).
    limit(50).
    sort({_updated_at : -1}).then((artworks) =>{
        if (isEmptyObject(artworks)){
      throw ARTWORK_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    return res.send(artworks);
  })
```

I'm passing into `keywordArray = ["photography"]` and `artistArray =["Joe Shmoe"]`.

I'm following the exact instructions from MongoDB's [tutorial on the logical operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/). I don't get any syntax errors, but I do get `ARTWORK NOT FOUND` exceptions being thrown.

Searching by artist names works great:

```
 Artwork.find({  _p_artist: {$in: artistArray}})
```

So does searching only keywords also works great:

```
Artwork.find({
      artworkKeywords: {
      $in: keywordArray}
```

But not both together with the `or` clause! What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/or/) or "either" means to express as "separate documents". You put all the query in to "one document" [which means "AND"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#specify-and-conditions)

```
   Artwork.find({ 
     $or: [
      { artworkKeywords: { $in: keywordArray } }, // each separate
      { _p_artist: { $in: artistArray } }          // just like separate queries
     ]
   })
```

So a "list" of different documents is the argument to "OR". What you wrote may as well have been:

```
Artwork.find({ 
  artworkKeywords: { $in: keywordArray },
  _p_artist: { $in: artistArray } 
})
```

Because that was basically your "one element" in the list, so it's a single "AND" condition instead of "OR".

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand your answer frankly. You say that you pass in a list of different documents to the argument of `$or`. But in the tutorial page I linked, the arguments are not different documents:`db.inventory.find( { $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: 10 } ] } )`. `price` and `quantity` are different properties of the same object. So I'm not sure how to begin fixing my code.

Comment: @YuChen What you are missing is "counting the brackets". There are **two** documents in the documentation example `[ { "quantity": { .. } }, { "price": .. } ]`. That's 1. as `{ "quantity": { .. } }`. and 2. `{ "price": .. }`. You tried to use **one** within the `$or`, and this "does nothing" like I explain. Is not the most simple way to understand to actually run the query statement and see it works?

Comment: thanks. I now understand what you were saying. I didn't run the query because I didn't see what the difference was between what you had written and your answer code.

Comment: @YuChen You also might discover the ["upvote"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) function here when you get "useful explanatory answers" like... Possibly something comes to mind Seems to be missing from your general activity.

Comment: Are you referring to me upvoting your answer? Isn't accepting your answer a pretty good indicator that I find it useful?

Comment: @YuChen [When should I vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote). You need to read the things you don't seem to understand.